# Python regex to remove punctuation except from URLs and decimal numbers

Tags: python, regex, nltk

People,

I need a regex to remove punctuation from a string, but keep the accents and URLs. I also have to keep the mentions and hashtags from that string.

I tried with the code below but unfortunately, it replaces the characters with accents but I want to keep the accents.

```
import unicodedata

if __name__ == "__main__":
    text = "Apenas um teste com acentuação. Para pontuação também! #python @stackoverflow http://xyhdhz.com.br" 
    text = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', text).encode('ascii','ignore')
    print text
```

The output for the following text **"Apenas um teste com acentuação. Para pontuação também! #python @stackoverflow http://xyhdhz.com.br"** should be **"Apenas um teste com acentuação Para pontuação também #python @stackoverflow http://xyhdhz.com.br"**

How could I do that?

Comment: You should provide the code of what you have tried, one or two examples of input and desired output for them.

Comment: @trincot Thanks. I edited the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python's [regex module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-contents) and `re.sub()` to replace any characters you want to get rid of. You can either use a blacklist and replace all the characters you don't want, or use a whitelist of all the characters you want to allow and only keep those.

This will remove anything in the bracketed class of characters:

```
import re

test = r'#test.43&^%à, è, ì, ò, ù, À, È, Ì, Ò, ÙÃz'
out = re.sub(r'[/.!$%^&*()]', '', test)
print(out)
# Out: #test43à è ì ò ù À È Ì Ò ÙÃz
```

(tested with Python 3.5)

To keep URLs you will have to do a little more processing to check for that format (which is pretty varied). What kind of input/output are you looking for in that case?

edit: based on your added input example:

```
test = "Apenas um teste com acentuação. Para pontuação também! #python @stackoverflow" 
# Out: Apenas um teste com acentuação Para pontuação também #python @stackoverflow
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't right the output here due to the mentions. I'll put it in the original post